# Double Linked Lists using node

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to create an add function that will add a new element to a linked list using a node, but for some reason its not working, i think i'm doing it wrong.

this is my code so far:

```
public void add(int pos, T e){

    Node<T> active = this.head;
    Node<T> pre = null;

    int counter = 0; 

    while ((active != null) && (counter < pos)){
        pre = active;
        active = active.getRight();
        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    if (counter == pos){

        Node<T> mynode = new Node<T>(e);


        if (pre == null){
            this.head = mynode;
            pre.setLeft(mynode);
        }
        else{
            pre.setRight(mynode);
            this.tail = mynode;
        }


        mynode.setRight(active);        
        mynode.setLeft(pre);
    }       


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A) Add Method on Doubly Linked List

On **Doubly Linked List**, a simple add method is as below;

```
// add method for single node
public void add(T value) {
    if(head == null)
        head = new Node<T>(value);
    else {
        Node<T> temp = head;
        while(temp.next != null)
            temp = temp.next;

        tail = temp.next = new Node<T>(value);
        tail.prev = temp;
    }

    size++;
}
```

However, you want to add to a specific position in the list;

### B) Position Add Method on Doubly Linked List

```
// add method for specific position
// pos must be smaller/equal than the size of the list
public void addPos(int pos, T value) {
    if(pos > size) // pos must be smaller/equal than size
        return;

    Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(value);
    size++;

    if(pos == 0) {
        newNode.next = head;
        head.prev = newNode;
        head = newNode;

        return;
    } else if(pos == size-1) {
        tail.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = tail;
        tail = newNode;
    } else {
        Node<T> temp = head;
        for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
            temp = temp.next;

        // insert newNode in the middle of temp.prev and temp
        // temp.prev <-> newNode <-> temp

        // attach newNode's prev and next references
        newNode.next = temp;
        newNode.prev = temp.prev;

        // attach adjacent node's references to newNode
        temp.prev.next = newNode;
        temp.prev = newNode;
    }
}
```

### C) Doubly Linked List Class

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> {

    protected Node<T> head;
    protected Node<T> tail;
    private int size;

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    // Overloaded add method for T[] list
    public void add(T[] list) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            add(list[i]);
    }

    // add method for single node
    public void add(T value) {
        if(head == null)
            head = new Node<T>(value);
        else {
            Node<T> temp = head;
            while(temp.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;

            tail = temp.next = new Node<T>(value);
            tail.prev = temp;
        }

        size++;
    }

    // add method for specific position
    // pos must be smaller/equal than the size of the list
    public void addPos(int pos, T value) {
        if(pos > size) // pos must be smaller/equal than size
            return;

        Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(value);
        size++;

        if(pos == 0) {
            newNode.next = head;
            head.prev = newNode;
            head = newNode;

            return;
        } else if(pos == size-1) {
            tail.next = newNode;
            newNode.prev = tail;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {
            Node<T> temp = head;
            for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
                temp = temp.next;

            // insert newNode in the middle of temp.prev and temp
            // temp.prev <-> newNode <-> temp

            // attach newNode's prev and next references
            newNode.next = temp;
            newNode.prev = temp.prev;

            // attach adjacent node's references to newNode
            temp.prev.next = newNode;
            temp.prev = newNode;
        }
    }

    public static class Node<T> {

        protected T value;
        protected Node<T> prev;
        protected Node<T> next;

        public Node(T value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = null;
            this.prev = null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value.toString();
        }

    }

    public void printList() {
        System.out.print("List         : ");

        if(head == null)
            System.out.printf(" <empty>\n");
        else {
            Node<T> temp = head;

            while(temp != null) {
                System.out.print(temp + " ");
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public void printReverse() {
        System.out.print("List Reversed: ");

        if(head == null)
            System.out.printf(" <empty>\n");
        else {
            Node<T> temp = tail;

            while(temp != null) {
                System.out.print(temp + " ");
                temp = temp.prev;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

}
```

### D) Test Code

```
public class TestDoublyLinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list = new DoublyLinkedList<>();

        Integer[] intList = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
        list.add(intList);

        printState(list);

        list.addPos(3, 88);

        printState(list);
    }

    public static void printState(DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list) {
        list.printList();
        list.printReverse();
        System.out.println("Head: " + list.head);
        System.out.println("Tail: " + list.tail);
        System.out.println("Size: " + list.getSize());
        System.out.println("************************\n");
    }
}
```

### E) Output

```
List         : 1 3 5 7 9 
List Reversed: 9 7 5 3 1 
Head: 1
Tail: 9
Size: 5
************************

List         : 1 3 5 88 7 9 
List Reversed: 9 7 88 5 3 1 
Head: 1
Tail: 9
Size: 6
************************
```